# Can I use filezilla to transfer files into WAMP

Tags: wamp, filezilla

I am using WAMP as my local server and what I want to know is can I use filezilla to transfer my files across from my documents to the WAMP server?

If so how can this be done in filezilla, (what do I need to put in host name and do I need a username or password, I did not set one so do I need to set one and if so how?).

Thank You

Comment: I am guessing that your WAMP server is not the same machine as the one with the My Documents files on it correct?

Comment: No it is on the same computer. If I don't need to file transfer, then how can I use WAMP to access my other php files from the "www" folder? I can only access localhost which shows the index.php file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need FileZilla for what you are after. You simply need to move your files from `My Documents` to the `www` directory of your Wamp installation. You can then point your URL at that file. So if you have a file `foobar.php` and drag it into `www` then you can access it at `http://localhost/foobar.php`.